How to build a conda-forge package relying on a custom YML file
I have developed a full python program based on several modules and libraries (e.g. biopython, pandas, ecc.). To achieve so, I have created a local environment where all the dependencies are stored and I am making it available here below.
name: ezmito
channels:
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=5.1=1_gnu
  - blast=2.5.0=hc0b0e79_3
  - boost=1.82.0=py311h06a4308_2
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h5eee18b_6
  - ca-certificates=2024.7.2=h06a4308_0
  - icu=73.1=h6a678d5_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.40=h12ee557_0
  - libboost=1.82.0=h109eef0_2
  - libffi=3.4.4=h6a678d5_1
  - libgcc-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libgomp=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libuuid=1.41.5=h5eee18b_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h6a678d5_1
  - mafft=7.505=hec16e2b_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h6a678d5_0
  - openssl=3.0.15=h5eee18b_0
  - pip=24.2=py311h06a4308_0
  - py-boost=1.82.0=py311h4cb112f_2
  - python=3.11.9=h955ad1f_0
  - readline=8.2=h5eee18b_0
  - setuptools=75.1.0=py311h06a4308_0
  - sqlite=3.45.3=h5eee18b_0
  - tk=8.6.14=h39e8969_0
  - wheel=0.44.0=py311h06a4308_0
  - xz=5.4.6=h5eee18b_1
  - zlib=1.2.13=h5eee18b_1
  - zstd=1.5.5=hc292b87_2
  - pip:
      - argparse==1.4.0
      - bcbio-gff==0.7.1
      - biopython==1.84
      - cai2==1.0.5
      - click==8.1.7
      - contourpy==1.3.0
      - cycler==0.12.1
      - fonttools==4.54.1
      - itaxotools-pygblocks==0.1.0
      - kiwisolver==1.4.7
      - matplotlib==3.9.2
      - numpy==2.1.1
      - packaging==24.1
      - pandas==2.2.3
      - pillow==10.4.0
      - pybedtools==0.10.0
      - pycirclize==1.7.1
      - pyfiglet==1.0.2
      - pyparsing==3.1.4
      - pysam==0.22.1
      - python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
      - pytz==2024.2
      - scipy==1.14.1
      - six==1.16.0
      - tzdata==2024.2
prefix: /home/cc/anaconda3/envs/ezmito

Now, I would like to make it public by developing a conda-build package, in order to install my program as conda install MYPACKAGE_NAME.
I have carefully read the conda-build guide but it's quite hard to understand where I should list all the required libraries.
Can you help me to better understand this part?

just a comment because i don't know nothing about conda but it looks like the depends should be instead in a json file https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#info-index-json

I am not too familiar with specifying dependencies for conda packages, but I am quite ceratin that you are not able to set pip dependencies, if there were, then conda would give part of the dependency resolution out of its own hand, risking to break an existing environment without the user realizing what is happening.

You most likely also don't depend on all those packages. Rethink your requirements and limit it to the packages and versions that you rely on directly and make sure that they are available from conda channels.

The YAML file you have is a conda environment recipe, rather than a recipe for building a package (meta.yaml).
Conda channels (e.g. bioconda, conda-forge) have their own specific guides and methods for building packages hosted in those channels. It looks like you might be intending your package to be part of bioconda, their contribution guide is here: https://bioconda.github.io/contributor/index.html
In addition, you can browse examples of existing bioconda recipes in their GitHub repository: https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes. That can help you find a package that is similar to your own to see how they structured theirs.
